# Как сделать подсветку кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении на кнопку, кнопка должна подсвечиваться, а когда пользователь уберёт мышь-перестанет светиться

```html
   <!-- задаю для всех div-ов класс price -->
<style>
.price {
display:inline-block;
width:400px;
color:blue;
}
</style>

<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;">
<!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
<div id="resizable">
    <!--"подрасчёт 1.1"-->
    <table align="center">
        <br>
            <p align="center">Глубина установки конца заливочных труб</p>
            <tr>
                <td height="40px">
                    <div class="price" title="H1">Расстояние от устья скважины до нижних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
                    <input name="t1" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h1" data="4550">
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td height="40px">
                <div class="price" title="H2">Расстояние от устья скважины до верхних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
                <input name="t2" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h2" data="4566">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td height="40px">
                <div class="price">Интервал отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
                <input name="t3" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="l1">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td height="40px">
                <div class="price">Плотность цементного раствора, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
                <input name="t4" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pup"  data="1800">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td height="40px">
                <div class="price">Плотность жидкости, находящейся в скважине, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
                <input name="t5" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pzh" data="1080">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
                    <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить Демо" id="demo">
                        <input type="text" name="res" size="10" id="l">
            </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.price {
display:inline-block;
width:400px;
color:blue;
}
input[type="button"]:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px white;
}
```

```html
<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;">
<!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
<div id="resizable">
<!--"подрасчёт 1.1"-->
<table align="center">
<br>
<p align="center">Глубина установки конца заливочных труб</p>
<tr>
<td height="40px">
<div class="price" title="H1">Расстояние от устья скважины до нижних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
<input name="t1" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h1" data="4550">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price" title="H2">Расстояние от устья скважины до верхних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
<input name="t2" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h2" data="4566">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Интервал отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
<input name="t3" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="l1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Плотность цементного раствора, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
<input name="t4" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pup"  data="1800">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Плотность жидкости, находящейся в скважине, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
<input name="t5" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pzh" data="1080">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить Демо" id="demo">
<input type="text" name="res" size="10" id="l">
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```